# Find minimal polynomial of transformation of adding its derivative to a polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, minimal-polynomials

We are asked to find the minimal polynomial of this transformation:

$T:\mathbb C_n[x] -> \mathbb C_n[x]$

$T(p) = p'+p$

What I did:

I found the transformation matrix with respect to the standard base (lets call it $s$):

$T(1)=1$, $T(x)=1+x$, ... $T(x^k)=kx^{k-1}+x^k$

Luckily it's an upper triangular matrix. So the characteristic polynomial is very easy to find and it is: $p_T(\lambda) = (1-\lambda)^n$ but how do I find the minimal polynomial? how do I find $k \leq n$ such that $(I-[T]_s)^k=0$??

Also it would seem that this matrix is not diagonlizable, so they are not equal...

Comment: For the record: whether or not the minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomials agree is **not equivalent** to whether the matrix is diagonalisable. In case of multiple roots of the characteristic polynomial one even has an opposite relation: those polynomials being equal is incompatible with the matrix being diagonalisable (both cannot simultaneously be true, though both could be false). There is on the other hand an equivalence of being diagonalisable in terms of the minimal polynomial alone, namely iff it splits into _distinct_ linear factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: check that the nilpotency degree of the $\;n\times n\;$ matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&*&*&\ldots&*\\0&0&*&\ldots&*\\\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
0&0&0&\ldots&0\end{pmatrix}$$

is $\;n\;$ (when the first diagonal over the main one is not all zeros, of course)

Comment: it's true. if $A$ is an $n$ by $n$ upper triangular matrix with 1 on the diagonal, then $(I-A)^n = 0$ how does this help us?

Comment: *Nilpotency degree*, @OriaGruber: the **minimal** such exponent !

Comment: So I was wrong? The transformation is diagonlizable?

Comment: Not even close, @Oria: for that it'd have to be that the matrix's minimal polynomial is the product of *different* linear factors...!

Comment: But what you said is that $m_A = (1-\lambda)^n$ but that is also the characteristic polynomial, isn't that a property of a diagonal matrix? that $m_A = p_A$

Comment: Not at all, @OriaGruber. A matrix is diagonalizable (over some field) iff its minimal polynomial is the product of *different* linear factors iff there exists a basis for the corresponding linear space all of which elements are eigenvectors of the matrix...In short: your matrix would be diagonalizable iff $\;x-1\;$ was its minimal polynomial iff $\;A-I=0\iff A=I\;$ ...